# Data on difference between elephant/deadlift bar and stiff bar on sumo deadlift?

Tags: deadlifts, powerlifting

From what I understand, the elongated, less-stiff bars allow for using the bending to gain some height (and momentum) before the full weight is off the floor. This can be beneficial if the/a sticking point is located at the floor*, or below the maximum bend height for a given weight.

On the other hand, Eddy hall [supposedly](https://barbend.com/elephant-bar-deadlift-record/) indicated the elephant bar can also be considered harder, for example because it can oscillate at a different frequency (and I assume with a larger amplitude).

Is there a dataset available on 1 rep max values on sumo deadlifts for lifters using a stiff bar and an elephant and/or deadlift bar?

- *With at the floor* I mean the height of the barbell when the plates touch the floor whilst the barbell is untouched/in rest.

Comment: *"Is there a dataset available on 1 rep max values on sumo deadlifts for lifters using a stiff bar and an elephant and/or deadlift bar?"* >> I'm not sure if this is available but if you find something, take into account where it's from. For example, certain powerlifting federations use an elephant bar for deadlifts, but they are also untested.

Comment: Given that the elephant bar is almost exclusively used in strongman competition, and sumo deadlifts are not permitted in strongman, I think it would be extremely unlikely that such a dataset would exist.

Comment: USPA uses high-whip bars (recently started using the Kabuki Strength deadlift bar which bends quite a bit), and they have tested competitions now.  So I supposed the way to do it is compare the tested competitions of the USPA with the USAPL.  The only difference between the two from that is the weigh in times (24 hours vs 2 hours).